# Why is my image not showing in the carousel?

Tags: image, path, carousel

Hi I created a carousel with help of bootstrap, when I add an image from the directory it doesn't show. I am almost sure it has something to do with the rootpath.

/Users/kosman/code/ganzon/siebas/testwebsite/app/assets/images

```
    <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="images/avocado.png" alt="First slide"/>
    </div>
```

What do I miss here ..

thank you

Comment: try this : <img src="assets/images/avocado.png" alt="First slide"/>

Comment: nothing happens when i try this